# What is the best way to store blobs in rails 5?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a sound recorder application (rails 5). I currently have the application able to start recording, stop recording, and save the recording (.wav) to the public directory. I am generating a blob, but am not currently doing anything with it as I don't really "know what to do with it."

The purpose of this application is to be able to record your own audio and save it to your user profile within the application and then do other various things with the data later. I have used carrierwave and paperclip before for managing multipart data, but I haven't worked with audio files so I'm not sure best practices. Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Storing actual files on the server itself is not scalable, so that is out of the question.
2. Storing blobs in the database. This could work, but I'm not sure if there is going to be noticeable inefficiency when converting back to audio from blob as well as lost data.
3. Storing blobs on aws. Basically the same thoughts as #2 with lost data and inefficiency when converting.
4. Storing actual files on aws. Assuming this is possible. Could get to be fairly large in bucket size if allowing long audio.

I'm really leaning towards using blobs within my database (#2) to exclude the use of 3rd party APIs if it is a good practice to do so. If this is a good option, how would I go about storing the blob in the database? I'm seeing `bytea` as the datatype from a few other responses, but what would get stored in there? The whole blob?

Example:

> data:audio/wav;base64,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.....

If this isn't the best option, could you let me know which the best would be and how to achieve it?

Edit: Sorry spoilers don't work as I expected them to.

#### Edit 2: Some other questions.

I'm not sure what I actually need to provide the `attach` method following https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html. Right now I have my audio passing to my controller as a file:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff58958a788 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xb/zm03wqls70gf3thlfy0d67bh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20190414-15311-1essuud.wav>, @original_filename="1555288144507.wav", @content_type="audio/wav", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"; filename=\"1555288144507.wav\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/wav\r\n">
```

I have tried a lot of different variations of this, but am getting files saved in my storage dir as crazy looking files.

```
current_user.audio_recordings.attach(
  io: audio, 
  filename: 'file.wav', 
  content_type: 'audio/wav'
)
```

It seems like I might be doing a lot more heavy lifting in JS than I need to be possibly.

JS saving function:

```
function saveRecording() {
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append("audio", recordingBlob, (new Date()).getTime() + ".wav");

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/landing_pages/save_audio");
    request.send(data);
    request.onload = function(oEvent) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
        console.log("Uploaded");
      } else {
        console.log("Error: " + request.status);
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PostgreSQL, I would advise against saving it as `bytea` and as `BLOB`, you can read about the benefits here.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB#bytea

https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql

Instead if you go down the path of saving it in your cloud provider, Rails 5 introduced ActiveStorage which is an easy to use framework for file storage on multiple backends.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I think ActiveStorage sounds like a good choice for a PoC and maybe even full scale.

Comment: is there anyway you can take a look at my new edits? I'm not following what I should be passing into the attach method for ActiveStorage. I'm getting files saved, but they look like binaries and have no extensions.

Comment: Can you explain your new question further?

Comment: When using the attach method of ActiveStorage, `current_user.audio_recordings.attach()`, it is creating a file inside of my storage directory, but it isn't a .wav as I would expect, it is a binary.

I'm not sure what I need to be passing to the `io` portion of the `attach` method, or if I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: I was completely wrong, it just strips the extension when it is stored, everything is good to go. Thanks! :)